# Gitosis won't create repository

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm testing my new Git repository. I converted from Subversion to Git, no problem.

Now, on my laptop

```
git remote add origin git@server:test.git
```

returns correctly. But when I do

```
git push
```

I get

> error:gitosis.serve.main:repository read access denied

And when I go to `/srv/git/repositories` on the server, the new repository isn't created.

Is there a log file that I can look at somewhere to figure out what's going on?

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carefully follow the "Setting Up" portion of the README. It describes access control. You'd be much better off using [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) instead. It's easier to use and better-documented. Gitosis is pretty much dead.

Answer (score 1):

Repositories cannot be created with `git push`. You have to use `git init --bare` on the server for that.

Comment: Why bare? Maybe he starts with code on the 'server'? (GIT doesn't really have servers though...)

Comment: @rudie: most of the time it's a bad idea to push into a non-bare repository, as it will bring your working tree and index out of sync. if he wants to have a worktree on the server, he's better off using hooks to call `fetch`+`reset --hard` from another repository containing the worktree.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and switched to [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). After tracking down some SSH issues it worked fine. Gitolite generates the repositories on the server when you push it.