# Gitosis / Git does not execute post-commit hook

Tags: hook, gitosis, githooks

I just set up Trac and Gitosis and wanted to control the ticket workflow with the commit messages.
Unfortunately my post-commit hook is not executed. If I execute it on command line (as gitosis user) everything is like charm.

My post-commit is rather simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/commited
echo 'Cant touch this!'
```

Any suggestions on that?

Thanks in advance & cheers
Martin

Comment: Trying using Gitolite (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7044873/6309) instead of gitosis: everything works better. You can use the non-root method to install your Gitolite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339272/gitolite-can-connect-via-ssh-cant-clone/9340778#9340778

Comment: I've set up gitolite - the hook is not executed.

Comment: Is it still working when you are executing the commit with the command-line?

Comment: Ouch - the answer is really simple and if I had thought about it a minute, I don't had to ask it.
All I wanted was the post-receive hook, not post-commit. Shame on me!

Comment: Good point. I have added references in an answer below for more visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP realized in the comment there was a difference between;

- [post-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925850/how-to-automatically-push-after-committing-in-git) (which is a **client-side hooks**, executed on commit when done locally.
- [post-receive hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981152/git-post-receive-hook-in-php/8983347#8983347) (which is a **server-side hook**, executed after a push)

See [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) for more.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623208/how-to-execute-a-command-right-after-a-fetch-or-pull-command-in-git/5623947#5623947 for more on the post-receive hook.